# Are all Ubuntu update download servers HTTP only?

Tags: update-manager, security, https

In Update Manager's software sources, the option exists to choose a download server and protocol like shown below.

**Do all updates download via HTTP only?**

And if HTTPS (or SFTP) aren't supported, why does the option exist? Related question [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/201643/), though it only deals with full ISO images.

[image: Choose a download server screenshot]

Comment: Does the protocol not change per download server? (if you choose ftp.rezopole.net I would expect it to change to ftp). And if the server supports https I'd expect it to show https.

Comment: @Rinzwind No, selecting one of the ftp links also displays http only, there are no other options to choose from.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### software supported protocols

Potentially yes the software showing the drop-down of protocols can support a https mirror - the drop-down box in question accepts the following valid *protocols*:

- ftp
- http
- file
- rsync
- https

This is detailed in the software-properties-gtk package source code:

```
apt-get source software-properties-gtk
cd software-properties*/softwareproperties/gtk
```

Look in the file **DialogMirror.py** - function `def is_valid_mirror`

### there is a but...

However in reality, the public mirrors Ubuntu supports is limited to `http://`, `ftp://` & `rsync://`

The mirrors you can define is limited when you define a [new mirror](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors):

- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+newmirror

### local mirrors

Therefore, since the software itself does not limit the protocols, one way to download over HTTPS is to define and maintain your own local repository & mirror.  As usual we have a great Q&A that have several applicable answers:

- [How to create a local APT repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-make-my-own-local-repository)

`apt-mirror` is probably your best bet here.  Install the `apt-mirror` package and examine its man page:

> CONFIGURATION EXAMPLES
>          The mirror.list configuration supports many options...
>
> ```
>    HTTPS with sending Basic HTTP authentication information (plaintext username and password) for all
>    requests: (this was default behaviour of Wget 1.10.2 and prior and is needed for some servers with new
>    version of Wget) set auth_no_challenge 1 deb https://user:pass@example.com:443/debian stable main contrib
>    non-free
>
>    HTTPS without checking certificate: set no_check_certificate 1 deb https://example.com:443/debian stable
>    main contrib non-free
> ```

As you can see, you can define a local HTTPS mirror - add your [local HTTPS mirror](https://askubuntu.com/a/184334/14356) and it should appear in the list of mirrors.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I wonder how vulnerable updates are to tampering then? Since HTTP traffic can be manipulated by your ISP, or even a coffee shop offering free WiFi, there must be something in place to verify the integrity of downloads. Probably asked & answered here (I'll try a search) but I'm not quite understanding how this works yet.

Comment: @TomBrossman - the system builds upon package authentication - this is one Q&A that explains this http://askubuntu.com/questions/75565/why-am-i-getting-authentication-errors-for-packages-from-an-ubuntu-repository

Comment: Interesting Guardian Project article [here on package metadata leakage](https://guardianproject.info/2014/10/16/reducing-metadata-leakage-from-software-updates/) for non-HTTPS connections.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu doesnt own those servers.It is upto them to decide if they will have https or not.
The option exists because a server might also provide https connection